# Type specified for TypedQuery is incompatible with itself

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring & Hibernate. I have a method in following fashion:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<SomeEntityClass> getSomeData(Integer someParam1, Long someParam2) {

    TypedQuery<SomeEntityClass> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT sec FROM SomeEntityClass sec " +
                    "WHERE sec.someField1 = :param1 " +
                    "AND sec.someField2 = :param2 ", SomeEntityClass.class);
    query.setParameter("param1", someParam1);
    query.setParameter("param2", someParam2);

    try {
        return query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new LinkedList<>();
    }
}
```

This method is part of web socket handler and is called when a message is received. However, when it does, I get following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
   Type specified for TypedQuery [some.package.subpackage.SomeEntityClass] is incompatible 
    with query return type [class some.package.subpackage.SomeEntityClass]
```

I have found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972979/type-specified-for-typedquery-class-is-incompatible-with-query-return-type-cla) and the provided answer indicated class being loaded from different class loaders. However:

```
ClassLoader a = UserMicroscopeLensLight.class.getClassLoader();
ClassLoader b = em.getClass().getClassLoader();

a.equals(b)
```

Yields

```
true
```

**EDIT: 2018-02-08 14:05 CET**

---

So I debugged through the code and got into `AbstractEntityManagerImpl.class` decompiled from byte code and got following lines:

```
if (!resultClass.isAssignableFrom(hqlQuery.getReturnTypes()[0].getReturnedClass())) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type specified for TypedQuery [" + resultClass.getName() + "] is incompatible with query return type [" + hqlQuery.getReturnTypes()[0].getReturnedClass() + "]");
}
```

The `resultClass.getClassLoader()` gave:

```
RestartClassLoader@9995
```

whereas `hqlQuery.getReturnTypes()[0].getReturnedClass().getClassLoader()` (and also `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` resulted in:

```
Launcher$AppClassLoader@10034
```

Funny thing is that, calling `em.getClass().getClassLoader()` in the query method results in:

```
RestartClassLoader@9995
```

So I'm asking... WTF?! Looking at the trace:

```
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source:-1)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.createQuery(Unknown Source:-1)
at some.package.name.SomeDaoImpl.getSomeData(SomeDaoImpl.java:21)
```

Iit seems that, the entity manager for called in `getSomeData` is just a proxy to some `SharedEntityManager` and they both have different class loaders...

Comment: Your error message indicates that the query return type is of class, not of SomeEntityClass.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? All other queries in the system are built this way. And I've checked if the bindings in the entity are ok. And they are.

See more in discussion with @coladict

Comment: The log says [some.package.[...]] and [**class** some.package[...]]. I really don't have any ide why this could haben. What does the debugger say? Are you sure the instances are the same? Is there any way to add some code, making your example a fully reproducible [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the issue. Removing spring dev tools resolved everything:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Idea came from [Spring's github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3316).

Answer (score 2):

This definitely looks like a classloader issue. To confirm it, try this code fragment. I'm only posting it as an answer, because I can't fit it in a comment.

```
for (EntityType e : em.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
    if (e.getJavaType().getName().equals(SomeEntityClass.class.getName())) {
        assert(e.getJavaType().equals(SomeEntityClass.class));
    }
}
```

If the assertion fails, then the class is indeed loaded twice.

Comment: Well, the assertion didn't fail. Any ideas?

Haven't thought of checking it this way though. Thanks.

Comment: Well, other than printing every `e.getJavaType.getName()` in the logs to see if it even enters that `if` block, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Additional info: When I run the same query (same method called) in `@PostConstruct` method of an `@Autowired` component which results in query being run at the startup of application, this query works fine.

The best thing is. It will also work when called later in the same place where it failed. This however results in the same type of error but in different method and different query.

PS. It enters the IF statement. The assertion is just correct for some reason.